# Kotlin return null after timeout

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

How does kotlin return null after a given timeout, even though the given suspend block isn't cancellable?

I tried using withTimeout and withTimeoutOrNull. However, if the given running block of withTimeout isn't cancellable, withTimeout will not return null until the suspend block is finish. Just as the following code:

```
suspend fun main() {
    measureTime {
        withTimeoutOrNull(300) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                Thread.sleep(500)
            }
        }
    }.let {
        println("cost time: $it ") //it cost about 500ms, not 300ms
    }
}
```

How do I make it return null immediately after a timeout, instead of waiting for the running block to end.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code that we can run to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Coroutine cancellation does not work with thread blocking methods by default. Use [`runInterruptible`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-interruptible.html).

Comment: The short answer is: it is not possible to do reliably. JVM/Kotlin doesn't support aborting a running thread/coroutine forcefully. Cancellations and interruptions are cooperative. As said above, you can use `runInterruptible` to support a code that responds to interruptions, but if you do e.g. blocking I/O, then you can't abort it just like that. On the other hand, you can close the I/O resource. So it really depends on your specific case.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305044/kotlin-coroutine-withtimeout-does-not-cancel-when-using-withcontext-to-get-non-b?rq=2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kotlin coroutine withTimeout does not cancel when using withContext to get non-blocking code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305044/kotlin-coroutine-withtimeout-does-not-cancel-when-using-withcontext-to-get-non-b)

Answer (score 0):

```
suspend fun main() {
    measureTime {
        withTimeoutOrNull(300) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                delay(500)
            }
        }
    }.let {
        println("cost time: $it ") //it cost about 300ms, not 500ms
    }
}
```

if you want to know more about why, then check cooperative/cancellable topic. You can also check why it is not a good idea of calling blocking call in a non-blocking code.